# Launching django site with httpd or django-server

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How to host the Django site with httpd.I have read the documentation saying `modpython` is no longer supported.

So my question is that what is more common

1.To launch django with httpd or

2.To launch django with its own runserver.py

Comment: Never ever user the integrated runserver for production purposes. Its just a development server. I am not sure whether modwsgi isnt supported anymore, but for sure modpython isnt.

Comment: Sorry i meant modpython.i have corrected the question now

Comment: So just use mod_wsgi,it has a good documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Deploying Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/) in the documentation.